# Docker + Symfony - cache.WARNING: Failed to save key

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

Having `var/cache` and `var/sessions` mounted from the host to the container is causing a lot loading time. How could I ignore these directories so I wouldn't need to wait for var directory on my machine and container being synced?

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    var:
    vendor:

services:
    php:
        container_name: grozissaviems_php
        build:
            context: docker/php
            args:
                ENV: ${ENV}
                APP: symfony
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html:delegated
            - var:/var/www/html/var
            - vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/html/var/logs

    nginx:
        container_name: grozissaviems_nginx
        build:
            context: docker/nginx
            args:
                ENV: ${ENV}
        ports:
            - 5000:80
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html:delegated
            - var:/var/www/html/var
            - vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
            - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        command: "nginx"
```

After running container if I enter I get an error for cache permissions being incorrect.

If I launch a script to give var/* permissions

```
docker exec -it grozissaviems_php bash -c 'mkdir -p var/cache var/logs var/sessions'
docker exec -it grozissaviems_php bash -c 'chmod -R 777 var/cache var/logs var/sessions'
```

now for some reason page is loaded (with a broken layout, but no error), but in `dev.log` I get:

> cache.WARNING: Failed to save key
>   "%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D"
>   (array)
>   {"key":"%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D","type":"array","exception":"[object]
>   (ErrorException(code: 0):
>   rename(/var/www/html/var/cache/dev/pools/zjgXxX8mSM/5ed64142f0b543.18899510,/var/www/html/var/cache/dev/pools/zjgXxX8mSM/J/P/W1NfrOIzF1l75zOKFhaN):
>   No such file or directory at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:93)"}
>   []

Is there something wrong with my `docker-compose.yml`? Is there something I missed?

Comment: I think your issue is that paths you use in your `docker exec` are not right, try with absolute path instead of relative and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are mounting the `var` directory. That's not only unnecessary, but can be a potential problem setting permissions correctly and consistently between the host and the container.

Also, you have multiple redundant mounts. You mount the whole project first (`.:/var/www/html:delegated`), and then you mount `var` and `vendor`.

Instead of doing that, just mount exclusively what you need.

(Tangentially, you are also mounting `var` and `vendor` inside your nginx container. Neither of those are necessary inside the web-server container, so just remove them. On the webserver you only need the `public` directory).

Finally, instead of `chmod`ing your `var` directory, just make the directory owned by the same user that runs the PHP process (`www-data`, most of the time).

You do not show your `Dockerfile`, but since you have a build context and do not have an image name, you must be using one.

In my projects, what I do is to first create the needed directories:

```
RUN set -eux; \
        mkdir -p var/cache var/log var/session
```

And then, near the end of the build change their ownership:

```
RUN chmod g+s /var/www/html/var
RUN chown -R www-data /var/www/html/var;
```

This way any other directory created under `var` will inherit this permissions.

Comment: Does that mean that instead of mounting var and vendor I should just `- /var/www/html/var`? So changes in container would not be synced with my host?

Comment: There is no reason to "sync" changes in `var` from container to host or viceversa If you are going to "sync" something (during development only), that may be `var/log`. But then you mount **only** that, and nothing else.

Comment: But as you see from volume above `- .:/var/www/html:delegated` whole project is being synced. My project is slow so I would like to stop receiving `var` changes form container to my host. As you can see I tried to mount it, but that is giving me the permission problem

Comment: Do not mount the whole project. Just mount the directory you actually need during development. `src`, `config`, `bin`, `public` and maybe `vendor`. Do not mount the whole thing, but just what you need. And you definitely do not need to mount `var`.

Comment: Do I need to add the same volumes to nginx too?

Comment: No, not at all. As I've just added to this answer, in the nginx container you only need `public`.